# Outage Tracking Tool

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing

Is there any open source tool to track application outages/downtime?

I work in a testing project and sometimes due to some anomalies we can't do the normal system testing. I need a tool to track down the all sort outages / downtime. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you asking for a tool to detect outages/downtime, or just a tool for recording outages/downtime?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you check out Nagios. It is very flexible and has tons of plugins to help you monitor a wide variety of things.

http://www.nagios.org/download